# SQL: Связь один-ко-многим, если остальные записи не существуют

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброй ночи!

Задача состоит в следующем.

- Имеется таблица tbl_clients: id, uid, key
- Имеется таблица tbl_tasks: id, ..., key

Один task может иметь много clients. Если создать внешний ключ в таблице tbl_task, тогда отдаётся ошибка. Т.е. key сначала должен быть определён в clients, и затем можно добавлять значения в task с таким key. Но мне необходимо сначала иметь возможность добавить task, и clients вовсе может быть и не привязан к каким-то tasks.

Comment: _Но мне необходимо сначала иметь возможность добавить task_ Зачем? У вас задача может не иметь заказчика?

Comment: Если у вас несколько клиентов к одному task, то почему вы кладете клиента в сам таск, каким образом вы собираетесь в этом одном поле отразить несколько значений. Если у каждого клиента может быть не более одного task - то тогда надо в клиента класть task_id.

Comment: @Mirdin, task может быть связан с клиентами, а может быть и не связан, существовать независимо.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, так и сделал, настроил связь из clients в task.